# Awk print string with variables

Tags: variables, awk, printf

How do I print a string with variables?

Trying this

```
awk -F ',' '{printf /p/${3}_abc/xyz/${5}_abc_def/}' file
```

Need this at output

```
/p/APPLE_abc/xyz/MANGO_abc_def/
```

where `${3} = APPLE`
and `${5} = MANGO`

Comment: can you show `file` content ?

Answer (score 34):

`printf` allows interpolation of variables.  With this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
a,b,APPLE,d,MANGO,f
```

We can use `printf` to achieve the output you want as follows:

```
$ awk -F, '{printf "/p/%s_abc/xyz/%s_abc_def/\n",$3,$5;}' file
/p/APPLE_abc/xyz/MANGO_abc_def/
```

In `printf`, the string `%s` means insert-a-variable-here-as-a-string.  We have two occurrences of `%s`, one for `$3` and one for `$5`.

Answer (score 20):

Not as readable,  but the printf isn't necessary here.  Awk can insert the variables directly into the strings if you quote the string portion.

```
$ cat file.txt
1,2,APPLE,4,MANGO,6,7,8


$ awk -F, '{print "/p/" $3 "_abc/xyz/" $5 "_abc_def/"}' file.txt
/p/APPLE_abc/xyz/MANGO_abc_def/
```